# Syfmony2 - custom query in repository for a many to many relation

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have a *manyToMany* relationship between **players** and **coaches**. Each player can have many coaches and each coach can have many players.

I want to create custom query to recuperate all the players that are linked to a particular coach but I really don't know how to do that.

I really need to create a custom query in a repository that will recuperate all the players linked to a particular coach.

Here's the canvas of my repository function in **OSC\User\Entity\PlayerRepository**

```
public function findPlayersOfCurrentUser($user) { //The user id is the id linked to the player
        return $this->_em->createQuery('


        ');

    }
```

All my *many-to-many* relationships are working and therefore I have a table (named **user_player**) like the following that is generated:

```
user_id     player_id
   1            1
```

Finally, my question would be: What is the SQL query to *SELECT all the players in the* **OSCUserBundle:Player** that have `$user->getId()` as a Coach ?

I know what to do in words(

```
SELECT all the players from OSCUserBundle:Player WHERE id IN (SELECT all the player_id FROM user_player WHERE user_id = $user->getId()
```

) but not in via createQuery or createQueryBuilder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// PlayerRepository
public function findPlayersOfCurrentUser(User $coach) 
{ 
    return $this->createQueryBuilder("o")
        ->innerJoin("o.coaches", "c", "WITH", "c=:coach")
            ->setParameter("coach", $coach)
        ->getQuery()->getResult() ;

}
```

Presuming that user and coach are related using aliases `coaches` and `players` (plurals, as they should be).

Comment: Did you mean "Presuming that player and coach" and not user and coach since user and coach are in my case the same ?

Comment: when I put your code, it gives me the following error: Expected argument of type "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder", "array" given

Comment: Please update your question with relations between Player and Coach. I know they are the same but just do it and I will later explain why.

Comment: About QB error; you should have php file and line where the error has been thrown. Paste that line, my QB should work just fine. You probably have error in some other place.